# Is there an example of a sequence of functions that converges pointwise but $M_n$ does not converge to $0$, where $M_n=\sup_{x \in E} |f_n(x)-f(x)|$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

In Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* we have Theorem 7.9:

> Suppose for $x \in E$
>
> $$\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)=f(x)$$
>
> Put
>
> $$ M_n=\sup_{x \in E} |f_n(x)-f(x)|$$
>
> Then $f_n \to f$ uniformly if and only if $M_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Is there a sequence of functions $\{f_n\}$ which converges pointwise to some $f$ but $\lim_{n \to \infty} M_n \not = 0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many examples of this. In general, pointwise convergence does not imply uniform convergence. For instance,

1. Take $f_n(x) = x^n$ on $[0,1)$. Then $f_n$ converges pointwise to $0$, yet $M_n=\sup_{x\in[0,1)}x^n = 1$ for every $n$.
2. Take $f_n(x) = \chi_{[n,n+1]}(x)$, where $\chi_{[n,n+1]}$ is the characteristic function of the interval $[n,n+1]$ defined to be $1$ if $x$ is in $[n,n+1]$ and $0$ otherwise. Then $f_n\to0$ pointwise on $\Bbb R$ but $M_n=\sup_{x\in\Bbb R}f_n(x) = 1$ for every $n$.
3. We can even make an example where $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ pointwise but $M_n \to \infty$ as $n\to\infty$ by modifying the example in 2. Define $f_n(x) = n\cdot\chi_{[n,n+1]}(x)$. Then $f_n\to0$ pointwise on $\Bbb R$ but $M_n=\sup_{x\in\Bbb R}f_n(x) = n\to\infty$, so $\lim_{n\to\infty} M_n = \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are a lot of examples, e.g.
$$
f_n(x) = \frac{nx}{1+n^2 x^2},
\qquad x\in [0,1].
$$
This sequence converges pointwise to $f(x) = 0$, but $\sup_{x\in [0,1]} |f_n(x) - f(x)| = \frac{1}{2}$ for every $n$.